# isomorphism of algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G,K$, and $H$ be a finitely generated commutative group.

If $G\times K$ is isomorphic to $H\times K$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $H$.

Can you guys give me a hint? I don't know how to solve this

Comment: Hove you considered using [FTFGAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#Classification)?

Answer (score 1):

It is a consequence of the Fundamental Theorem that every finitely generated commutative group $G$ can be decomposed as a direct product of infinite cyclic group and finite cyclic groups of prime power order, and the orders of these indecomposable factors are uniquely determined by $G$. Your result follows easily from that, but it would be difficult to prove it without using the Fundamental Theorem.